# how to list content of zip file

Tags: zip, gunzip

I created a zip file which was very large in size, I then split the main zip into chunks of 3GB. I used the command

```
zip test.zip --out new_test.zip -s 3300m
```

which resulted into 3 files

```
test.zip
test.01
test.02
```

I then used `mv` command to put *.zip* at the end of other two files as well.

Now I have all 3 *.zip* files but when I try to list content of the zip file to redirect in a file I am getting following error.

```
unzip -l test.zip > test.txt
warning [bulk_content_import1.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon)
```

Can somebody please help me with this. There is no problem when I used `unzip -l test.zip | more` to view content but I want to redirect all file names into a separate *.txt* file.

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of test1.zip or
        test1.zip.zip, and cannot find test1.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: Why did you rename the files? `zip` might expect them to have the names that were given to them...

Comment: it was a requirement to name all the split files to be .zip as well. or if you have other recommendation please suggest me, so i can split the main .zip file into 2 or 3 equal size chunks with .zip extension. That will make life easier. I am stuck with this an need help

Comment: Consider creating symlinks back to the original zip filepart names?

Comment: Well, the individual parts of a multi-part zip file are useless without also having the other parts of the same multi-part zip file. You can't process them separately and there is no reason to rename them.

Comment: You can split a ZIP file into multiple, individually valid files using `zipsplit`, but it doesn’t support archives larger than 2GiB so it won’t apply in your case.

Answer (score 3):

This does not work as you think. You have created a multipart zip, not 3 zip files.

You cannot expect to rename the .01 and .02 parts to zip without breaking the integrity of the zip files. Furthermore the .01 and .02 parts do not have the initial header contents of the initial first .zip file.

So to list all contents of the 3-file multipart zip, you need to preserve the names as it is.

TLDR You cannot invent things and expect them to magically work as you *think* they work.

If you want smaller zip files, the easiest way is decompressing the big one, and distributing the files by smaller zip files.